# Can Dynamics NAV warehouse picks be updated via web service?

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I am building a C# console application that interacts with a Dynamics NAV web service in order to modify warehouse picks in NAV. Retrieving the pick lists and the associated items works perfectly, however, when I try to update a picking list I get HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. The curious thing about that is that my user has super-permissions in NAV and should, therefore, be able to do anything I want.

The pick lists are published as a Page via a SOAP web service.

The only thing that I can think of that would sort of make sense, is if you simply couldn't modify pick lists via a web service. Does anyone have some info on that?

```
var service = new PickList_Service();
var credential = new NetworkCredential("MYDOMAIN\USER","PASSWORD");
service.Credentials = credential;
var list = service.Read("LIST IDENTIFIER");
list.AssignedUserID = "SOME USER";
service.Update(ref list); //<-- this is where the exception with the HTTP error is thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you get unauthorized error, but if the goal is to modify the pick list and you can retrieve the data than why don't you just create a NAV codeunit with functions to modify pick list and publish it as a webservice.
Than it you would only require to call the mentioned codeunits method and pass there parameters retrieved from a part that already works (key or filters).